# Dataframe:Create new dataframe keeping duplicate on basis of multiple columns which are coming more then 2 times(Time constraint)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

**This ia sample code:**

```
data = {'Col1':  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
            'Col2': ['A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A3','A4','A4','A4','A1','a9','a9','A2'],
            'Col3': ['B1','B1','B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B5','B5','B1','b9','b9','B2'],
            'Col4': ['ab','bc','cd','da','da','da','df','fd','vf','sd','asd','sda','sdf'],
            }

    df2 = pd.DataFrame (data)

    counts_col2 = df2.groupby("Col2")["Col2"].transform(len)
    counts_col3 = df2.groupby("Col3")["Col3"].transform(len)
    
    mask = (counts_col2 > 2) & (counts_col3 > 2)

    df2[mask]
```

**output**

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0   0     A1    B1  ab
1   1     A1    B1  bc
2   2     A1    B1  cd
6   6     A4    B5  df
7   7     A4    B5  fd
8   8     A4    B5  vf
9   9     A1    B1  sd
```

1. Everything is right in it,But Since my data is huge
   is taking long time to execute.
2. So if any  better soultion can be used  for reducing time
3. **Any help would be apreciated**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Do not use `agg(len)`

You should aggregate with `size`, which is implemented quickly. That will give you a huge performance gain, and after that you can squeeze out a little bit more specifying `sort=False` in the `groupby`, So change your lines to:

```
counts_col2 = df.groupby("Col2", sort=False)["Col2"].transform('size')
counts_col3 = df.groupby("Col3", sort=False)["Col3"].transform('size')
```

#### Example of timings/equivalence:

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy


def agg_len(df):
    counts_col2 = df.groupby("Col2")["Col2"].transform(len)
    counts_col3 = df.groupby("Col3")["Col3"].transform(len)
    mask = (counts_col2 > 2) & (counts_col3 > 2)
    return df[mask]

def agg_size(df):
    counts_col2 = df.groupby("Col2")["Col2"].transform('size')
    counts_col3 = df.groupby("Col3")["Col3"].transform('size')
    mask = (counts_col2 > 2) & (counts_col3 > 2)
    return df[mask]

def agg_size_nosort(df):
    counts_col2 = df.groupby("Col2", sort=False)["Col2"].transform('size')
    counts_col3 = df.groupby("Col3", sort=False)["Col3"].transform('size')
    mask = (counts_col2 > 2) & (counts_col3 > 2)
    return df[mask]

#@ansev's solution
def map_value_counts(df)
    return df[df['Col2'].map(df['Col2'].value_counts()>2) &
              df['Col3'].map(df['Col3'].value_counts()>2)]


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda N: pd.DataFrame({'Col1': range(N),
                       'Col2': np.random.choice(np.arange(N), N),
                       'Col3': np.random.choice(np.arange(N), N),
                       'Col4': np.random.choice(np.arange(N), N)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: agg_len(df),
        lambda df: agg_size(df),
        lambda df: agg_size_nosort(df),
        lambda df: map_value_counts(df)
    ],
    labels=['Agg len', 'Agg size', 'Agg size No Sort', 'Map Value Counts'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(16)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,
    xlabel="~ Number of Groups"
)
```

[image]

Comment: will sort=false will affect result

Comment: @ZestyDragonques No because pandas will still align on the index when using the Boolean Mask. But with many groups it starts to have an appreciable impact on the result. Also in the above because I use `equality_check=np.allclose` this ensures the results are all essentially identical between all methods.

Answer (score 3):

Other good approach is [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
df2[df2['Col2'].map(df2['Col2'].value_counts()>2) &
    df2['Col3'].map(df2['Col3'].value_counts()>2)]
```

---

Taking data from @aLollz answer

```
%%timeit
df2[df2['Col2'].map(df2['Col2'].value_counts()>2) &
    df2['Col3'].map(df2['Col3'].value_counts()>2)]
31.2 ms ± 8.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%%timeit
df2[(df2.groupby("Col2")["Col2"].transform('size')>2) &
    (df2.groupby("Col3")["Col3"].transform('size')>2)]
40.5 ms ± 981 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
(counts_col2 > 2)
```

To

```
(counts_col2.to_numpy() > 2)
```

Comment: counts_col2.values taking 136 seconds

Comment: counts_col2.to_numpy() taking 136 seconds

Comment: can you provide any more efficient method